# Nesting a counter within another dictionary where keys are dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas dataframe with a format like:

```
    ID      Code
    E1023   a
    E1023   b
    E1023   b
    E1023   b
    E1024   b
    E1024   c
    E1024   c
```

I would like to create a dictionary with the ID column as a key, with values from the Code column and its counts for a particular ID nested inside like:

```
{'E1023' : {'a' : 1, 'b' : 3 } , {'E1024' : {'b' : 1, 'c' : 2}}}
```

I understand that I can use a Counter on the Code column, but how do I do this such that it is grouped by the ID and then nested within a dictionary where the ID is key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = {k: v.value_counts().to_dict() for k, v in df.groupby('ID')['Code']}
print (d)
{'E1023': {'b': 3, 'a': 1}, 'E1024': {'c': 2, 'b': 1}}
```

Or use `Counter` and then convert to `dict`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {k: dict(Counter(v)) for k, v in df.groupby('ID')['Code']}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! Will be making plenty of use of groupby and value_counts in the future

Comment: It seems my problem has further complexity which I don't know how to deal with - another level of nesting is required. Can I request your help by editing my original question or shall I make a new one?

Comment: @user3058703 - I think the best new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694178/nesting-a-dictionary-within-another-dictionary-grouping-by-values-in-a-pandas-d